# increase counter depending on array length

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this following problem:

I want to track visits of my blog posts so i had the idea to create an array called `visitorsIp` and push the ip adress from the visitor into the array with `$addToSet`.

Now i have an cronjob that should increase the `viewed` counter depending on the length of the array. and the array should be cleared at the end.

My document simplified:

```
{
   _ip: 5aösldkf3sdlfk2,
   viewed: 0,
   visitorsIp: ["192.168.200.20", "192.168.200.21", "192.168.200.22"]
}
```

I tried something like this here:

```
await Blog.aggregate([
    {
      $addFields: {
        counter: {
          $size: "$this.visitorsIp"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      viewed: {
        $add: ["$this.counter"]
      }
    }, 
    {
       visitorsIp: {
          $set: []
       }
    }
  ]);
})
```

Doesnt seems to work how i expected

My expected result is this here:

```
{
   _ip: 5aösldkf3sdlfk2,
   viewed: 3,
   visitorsIp: []
}
```

The `viewed` gets increased by 3 because the array size was 3. And the array is cleared after.

Comment: can you add your expected result.

Comment: @turivishal sure i added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `updateMany()` with pipeline,

#### [updateMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html)

- `$add` to sum the existing count + `$size` of total `visitorsIp`
- `visitorsIp` set empty `[]`

```
await Blog.updateMany({},
  [{
      $set: {
        "viewed": {
          $add:[{ $size:"$visitorsIp" }, "$viewed"]
        },
        "visitorsIp": []
      }
  }]
)
```

#### [update()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)

- need to set option `multi: true` for multiple documents update

```
await Blog.update({},
  [{
      $set: {
        "viewed": {
          $add:[{ $size:"$visitorsIp" }, "$viewed"]
        },
        "visitorsIp": []
      }
  }],
  { multi: true }
)
```

> Note: use updateMany() instead of update() because update() method is deprecated in mongoose.

Comment: this actually wont work, because you set `viewed` to the size of the array instead of incrementing `viewed`

Answer (score 2):

To update

```
db.getCollection('test').update(
  {},
  [{
    $set: {
      "viewed": {$add: [ {$size:"$visitorsIp"}, '$viewed' ]},
      "visitorsIp": []
      }
  }],
  {
    multi: true
  }
);
```

`viewed` is not a valid pipeline.

To `unset` visitorsIp, You need to have another query to set empty or unset `visitorsIp`. In single query, both cannot be referenced on the same field.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question, updated the answer.

Comment: almost working. the issue is that i want to increase the `viewed` instead of setting an value. `$inc` doesnt work in aggregation?

Comment: your second solution removes my array completly instead of setting it to `[]` this leads to the error of `the argument $size must be an array`

Comment: yea thats where i need help at

Comment: almost works, just need to stringify viewed like this `'$viewed'` and set `visitorsIp` back to `[]`

Comment: Sure, when you said the second answer thrown error. I removed that. Actually it had two options. One is to set and another to make empty. Glad. You solved.

Comment: @Gibbs nice just forgot to add `visitorsIp:[]` and `multi: true`, because this will update single document.

Comment: Thanks turivishal.